# Scala val and var related question and scala requiring me to assign a value at declaration

Tags: scala

I have a variable that I want to declare like:

```
val foo : Baz

for (s <- barList) {
 if s.tag == "java"
   foo = s
}
```

Once `foo` is assigned a value, `foo` cannot be reassigned. From this perspective `foo` is of type val and not var. But above is not valid scala code as scala forces to assign a value at the declaration time. Even if I use var, scala forces me to assign a value. Is there a better solution? The reason I would like val is because it results in better performance and val semantics fits in above scenario.

Comment: IMHO, you should not worry to much about performances, until you have a better understanding of Scala programming. Premature optimisation...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
val foo: Baz = barList.find(_.tag == "java").getOrElse( /* provide default here */)
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are looking at this from a C perspective - a variable, mutable or not, is just a memory address to place some value in.

In functional languages, though, a variable is a like a named expression (more or less). You declare: From here on, the thing on the left should be considered as it's the thing on the right. Just declaring the variable is an attempt to assign a name to nothingness.

If you, however do not care about such things you can use a `var` to store the value, update it or whatever you need and the reassign it to a `val`. Or just modify and use MageeS' solution.

Answer (score 5):

What about

```
val foo = barList.find(_.tag == "java")
```

Comment: That returns an `Option`, mind you. You could `get` after it to force the value (and get an error in its absence).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_`  to pass a default value to a `var` (for a `val` its quite useless):

```
var foo : Baz = _

for (s <- barList) {
  if s.tag == "java"
   foo = s
}
```

However, for this particular example, the solution of MageeS is better. If possible, avoid declaring `var`.

**Edit:** To address Jean-Phillipe comment. When inside the body of a function, if you cannot assign a reasonable default value. You should use  `Option`. The code becomes:

```
var foo : Option[Baz] = None

for (s <- barList) {
  if s.tag == "java"
   foo = Some( s )
}
```

After the loop, `foo` will still be equal to `None` if nothing was found, or equal to `Some(...)` where the dots replace the last element in `barList` whose tag is "java". You can retrieve this value with `foo.get`.